# Is there a way to switch layout inside the group of layouts?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

[image]

For example I want to have EN and RU groups. Inside EN group I have only one language. Inside RU I want to have RU and UA layouts. I want to configure <kbd>ALT+SHIFT</kbd> to switch between RU/EN groups and I want to use <kbd>WIN+SPACE</kbd> to switch between RU/UA layouts inside RU group.

Could it be possible?